# Resolving Kerberos vs NTLM Authentication Issue in Cross-Domain SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, ssms, kerberos

I am encountering an issue with Kerberos authentication in a multi-domain Microsoft SQL Server setup. Here are the details of my configuration:

1. Microsoft SQL Server is hosted on a server that is part of the Windows Active Directory `xyz.com` domain.
2. Host1, also in the `xyz.com` domain.
3. Host2, part of the Windows Active Directory `abc.com` domain, which has a two-way trust relationship with `xyz.com`.
4. A separate DNS server registers the SQL Server endpoint A record as `sqlserver-instance.differentdomain.com`.
5. I registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) `MSSQLSvc/sqlserver-instance.differentdomain.com` in the `xyz.com` domain.

- Connecting to sql server from SSMS on Host1, can connect to SQL Server using Kerberos authentication.
- Connecting to sql server from SSMS on Host2, defaults to NTLM authentication instead of Kerberos when connecting to SQL Server.

Despite this configuration, when Host2 tries to connect to `sqlserver-instance.differentdomain.com`, it uses NTLM instead of Kerberos.

Is there a solution that allows Host2 to use Kerberos authentication to connect to SQL Server while maintaining the endpoint sqlserver-instance.differentdomain.com? Additionally, I found a guide on configuring Kerberos with realms for Java applications (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). Can a similar approach be applied for non-Java environments, or is there an alternative method for my situation?

Comment: What happens if you run the following at command prompt `nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.xyz.com.` from Host2, and `nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.abc.com.` from the SQL Server machine? The Domain Controllers returned by those commands, can you `ping` them from each machine? Two way trust doesn't help if you don't have line-of-sight to the other domain's DC.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following to map the domain to the correct realm (note: Kerberos realm, not AD domain; realms are almost always upper-case as seen in `klist`):

1. Manual `ksetup /addhosttorealmmap .differentdomain.com XYZ.COM`.
2. The corresponding [Group Policy setting](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Kerberos::HostToRealm).

In Windows, typically it's not the client itself but the client's KDC responsible for mapping service domains to Kerberos realms. (The client requests a "local" ticket and potentially gets a referral to another realm.) So if possible, I would attempt to deploy this mapping to the domain controllers instead of client machines.

Comment: I have to try this one host2 only, right?
Tried this. looks like it should work, but not working actually.

Comment: @Raman I think you need to do it on the SQL Server machine also, because otherwise it doesn't know how to verify the Kerberos ticket.

Comment: The SQL Server machine only verifies tickets against its own service account, the client's realm doesn't matter.